# Does Space Ghost himself have any super human abilities?

Tags: space-ghost

As a kid, I always wondered if the cartoon super hero Space Ghost had any powers without his bands and belt. He was able to survive in space unaided [but that seemed to apply to all the Galaxy Space Stars, to some degree] and was unusually strong and durable, but not "inhumanly" so.

Were all of his abilities derived from his advanced tech, or was he more than merely an average Earth human?

Comment: "*Space Ghost is an interstellar cop, with a home base on the Ghost Planet. He is equipped with an inviso-button on his belt, which renders him invisible while also protecting him from harm with an invisible energy field. The power bands on his wrists are capable of emitting a variety of rays, which can freeze, fry, shock, or just plain blast the bad guys. He can both fly and (by dint of stupendous effort) teleport, but his usual method of getting around is in his space ship, The Phantom Cruiser. His companions in adventure include Jan and Jayce (teenage siblings), and Blip the Monkey.*"

Comment: Sounds like he's a tech superhero rather than a powered person; http://www.toonopedia.com/spacegh.htm

Comment: What cartoon featuring Space Ghost are you asking about? I haven't watched any of the shows he appears in but considering you say _"Galaxy Space Stars"_ I assume you are asking about _Space Stars_. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: He has the power to make celebrities feel vaguely uncomfortable

Comment: @Valorum I see what you did there, V! BUT.... should we really count _Coast to Coast_ as Space Ghost Canon?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I was speaking of all the action-toon versions, not counting _Space Ghost Coast to Coast_ .I am familiar with the 60s version, but recognize that "Canon" and even _origins_ in those early H-B toons are ...loose at best. The version from the 80s seemed to have a more coherent, super-story, comic-book like time line, due to the inclusion of various other heroes such as the _Teen Force_. This is why I referred to that iteration specifically.

Comment: @RussRainford - it ran for longer as *coast-to-coast* and had more viewers. Perhaps we might alsoask whether the original series is canon to the longer and more successful TV series